# do all android devices have non-removable external storage?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

This  [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#InternalVsExternalStorage)  here describes about the non removable external storage. 
does all the android devices have non removable external storage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this depends completely on the manufacturer. Devices like the Nexus S, Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4 have non removable external storage, while some devices like the Optimus One have only removable external storage. Some devices may even have two external storages, one a partition on the on board memory chip and another as an SD Card.

**EDIT**

As CommonsWare pointed out in the comments, as far as the standard Android SDK is concerned, you only have one external storage on the device (which you can get via [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)). As the documentation states, this will return the primary external storage in the event of the presence of more than one external storage:

> In devices with multiple "external" storage directories (such as both
>   secure app storage and mountable shared storage), this directory
>   represents the "primary" external storage that the user will interact
>   with.

Comment: Technically, at least through Android 4.2, a device will have exactly one external storage location, from the standpoint of Android SDK and the definition of the phrase "external storage". A device manufacturer may elect to support *additional* places where the manufacturer can store data (e.g., an SD card slot in addition to on-board external storage), but that is up to the device manufacturer and is not presently supported by the Android SDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare You're right, as usual :P I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: now I have one more question, i am writing my data into a file (can be public). ant the file path I've given is Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() . although this one seems to work on my nexus tablet, usually one some other devices it gives me error: Error writing into files /mnt/sdcard/my_directory.
can you please suggest me some solution for this issue. 
I've also tried using internal storage but I can't seem to find the data my app wrote.

Comment: @user1698550 That is a separate problem, and you should open another question for that. Also, you will not be able to see data on the internal storage using a file manager etc. as it is private to your app.

Answer (score 2):

From that link

> Because the external storage may be unavailable—such as when the user has mounted the storage to a PC or has removed the SD card that provides the external storage—you should always verify that the volume is available before accessing it.